TV series about game show in another world
There is this boy, quite sure he wears a red shirt and has blonde hair. he travels to this other world which seems kinda like a game show where he helps out and is friendly with the staff.
Near the end of the series the Game Show Host goes crazy and he starts trying to kiss the audience with some of them pulling up wooden cutouts. it's revealed he's a robot (may have been revealed sooner, this is the earliest i remember it) and it seems like the show has lost it's studio audience because of the incident.
in the boys own world there's this statue which kinda reminds me on a mime but has no face and is holding a clock, i think it's a symbol of the series as near the end the boy is standing in front of it i think contemplating something.
near the end of the series in the boy's own world there's this aurora which appears and i think scientists are investigating it as they can touch it. this aurora i think is connected/related to this game show world and the boy enters it. while he's in the aurora another version of the boy appears to talk to him and i got the feeling this was the boy's dark side or something. 
i think i also remember that the boy had an older role model who was with the scientists and fell into the aurora and the boy went into find him and get him out
It aired on Australian TV's ABC Chanel in the 1990's

This is Finders Keepers (AKA The Finder) from 1992:

The story revolves around a boy by called Patrick who, whilst playing on his computer, receives an invitation to take part on a TV game show called "Finders Keepers" through a store in a shopping arcade. He accepts the invitation and is sucked into another world where he is given clues to find missing treasures from his own world and take part in an interdimensional hunt.

The hero is a blonde boy who wears a red shirt in the opening credits. The first episode (and the rest) are available online, and the scene with the host going nuts and starting to kiss audience members (some of whom are cardboard cutouts) is in episode 9 around minute 3. And here's that mime-looking clock statue (from Youtube):


...and if this is the right answer, it's a duplicate.

Even so, your answer is better than the duplicate.
